# Send images to browser client

Tags: java, android

I am working on a Webserver on android and I was not able to send binary to the browser. Thanks in advance

> how do I send binary data to browser. Please, do it using outputstream and inputstream.

```
Socket soc=server.accept();
BufferedReader buff=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));

try{
    String req=buff.readLine().replace(" HTTP/1.0","").replace(" HTTP/1.1","").replace("GET ","");
//setTitle(req);
//buff.close();
File f=new File(homedir+req);
if(f.isDirectory()){
    File f2=new File(homedir+req+"/index.html");
    File f3=new File(homedir+req+"/INDEX.html");
    if(f2.exists()||f3.exists()){
        try{
        OutputStream out=soc.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(out);
        pw.print("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\rContent-type: text/html\n\r\n\r");
        pw.flush();
        //pw.close();
        FileInputStream inst=new FileInputStream(f2);
        copyStream(inst,out);
        out.close();
        pw.close();
        }catch(Exception k){
            OutputStream out=soc.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(out);
            pw.print("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\rContent-type: text/html\n\r\n\r");
            pw.flush();
            //pw.close();
            FileInputStream inst=new FileInputStream(f3);
            copyStream(inst,out);
            inst.close();
            out.close();
            pw.close();
        }
    }else
    throw new Exception("file not found");
}else{
OutputStream out=soc.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(out);
    String mim="";
    try{
        mim=MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(f.getName().substring(f.getName().lastIndexOf(".")+1));
    }catch(Exception k){
        mim="text/html";
    }
    if(mim.isEmpty()){
        mim="text/html";
    }
    pw.print("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\rContent-type: "+mim+"\n\r\n\r");
    pw.flush();
    //pw.close();
    FileInputStream inst=new FileInputStream(f);
    copyStream(inst,out);
    inst.close();
    out.close();
    pw.close();
    }
}catch(Exception k){
    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(soc.getOutputStream());
    pw.print("<html><h1>"+k.getMessage()+"</h1></html>");
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
}
buff.close();
soc.close();
```

> The browser shows the following when this is called:

```
OutputStream out=soc.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(out);
String mim="";
try{
               mim=MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(f.getName().substring(f.getName().lastIndexOf(".")+1));
}catch(Exception k){
    mim="text/html";
}
if(mim.isEmpty()){
    mim="text/html";
}
pw.print("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\rContent-type: "+mim+"\n\r\n\r");
pw.flush();
//pw.close();
FileInputStream inst=new FileInputStream(f);
copyStream(inst,out);
inst.close();
out.close();
pw.close();
```

*Here is what the browser shows:*

[image: What the browser shows]

Comment: Are you opposed to using OkHttp library to send a MultipartBody file request?

Comment: You used a PrintWriter and when done closed the output stream. After that you try to use the output stream again. That will not do of course.

Comment: `The browser shows the following when this is called:`??? The browser will not show that code. What do you mean?

Comment: `Here is what the browser shows:` You should tell what the browser receives instead. Use show source.

Comment: You are giving not enough info. You should try to tell what the receiving side is receiving exactly. Dont use a browser but HttpUrlConnection to download that image. So make a client app too. You see much better then what your server spp is doing.

Comment: `if(f2.exists()||f3.exists()) ... inst=new FileInputStream(f2);` ????

Answer (score 0):

Change here:

```
String mim="image/"

try{
               mim += MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(f.getName().substring(f.getName().lastIndexOf(".")+1));
```

**this code set proper Content-type for image like:**

```
image/jpg
image/jpeg
image/png
```

Comment: Okay, so when I do this the browser shows a `the_file.png download failed due to network errors` and tries to download the image instead of showing it.

Comment: the_file.png exists at server or not?

Comment: Yes the_file.png exists.